# Overlapping CSS in React, Webpack application

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have created an application using webpack and reactjs.
So far I have created 2 pages. I have defined CSS styling for both the pages. But when I load page 2 after loading page 1, the styles from page 1 are interfering with those of page 2.

For example

Page 1

```
require('style1.css');
var Page1 = React.createClass({
render: function(){
  return(
<div> <h1>This is Page1</h1> <span> hello from page1</span></div>
 )
}
});

module.exports = Page1;
```

style1.css

```
span {
   color : red
}
```

Page 2

```
require('style2.css');

var Page2 = React.createClass({
render: function(){
  return(
<div> <h1>This is Page2</h1> <span> hello from page2</span></div>
 )
}
});

module.exports = Page2;
```

style2.css

```
h1 {
   color : blue
}
```

When page2 is loaded after page1, the color of span was red, which was loaded from page1's style. Is there any way to avoid such kind of interferences or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could you show us how you pass from page 1 to page 2 ?
Is it with one parent component ? a router ?

Comment: Assuming it's a single page application, I'm not sure it will work the way you hope. Once it's loaded into the browser, the stylesheet doesn't simply disappear because you changed routes.

Comment: @Snahedis yes I am using react-router I didn't added the Link tag in the example.

Comment: @aw04 Yes it is a single page application. If the style sheet will not unloaded for each page what will be the best way to overcome the situation? The actual issue here is the styles from the landing page is killing my admin page style. How come I override the situation what will be the best solution any idea?  Should I have to rewrite all the styles of landing page not to interfere with the new page?

Comment: Why not apply those styles to the component rather than globally? For instance, instead of a h1 {..}, do .myComponent h1 {...}

Comment: Oh god, I didnt even think about this way.Thanks aw04 let me try this and let you know the result. Actually I was searching for the solution like unloading styles after loading a page etc. and I couldn't able to find out any answers.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can unload the styles or not to be honest, but either way I think that is overkill for this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have local stylesheets for each React component.

So the style sheet itself will have something like this:

```
:local(.styles) {

  .your-style{...}
}
```

You can store it in the same folder as your component code. You import the style like so:

```
/* component styles */
import { styles } from './styles.scss'
```

In the render function of your component you will have this:

```
return (
  <div className={styles}>
  ...
  </div>
)
```

Everything within that `<div>` will have the stylesheet applied.

Loader configuration for your Webpack:

```
loaders: [{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style!css?localIdentName=[path][name]--[local]!postcss-loader!sass',
}]
```

You can look at this awesome [boilerplate app](https://github.com/anorudes/redux-easy-boilerplate), that implements all of this very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is not going to fix the inherent problems with style sheets. If you want component level styling the simplest solution is to go with inline styles. You might also look at Radium. https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium

Comment: So we cannot unload style sheets once it is loaded right? OK thanks Stevens I will try radium and will let you know the result.