# Navigating to new page with new content and new css in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a complete beginner in ReactJS. I'm currently designing a website using it and currently working through localhost.
My main page is on localhost:3000 and I want to navigate to localhost:3000\University(I have designed a separate file University.js for this).

On navigating to the content of this file, it overlaps with the existing content (ie that of localhost:3000). Is there any way to show the new content without overlapping as well as with separate CSS. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: how are you navigating to the new page through the code? React Router?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm not getting what you mean by "overlapping content"! For the css part maybe you are looking for something like "local stylesheets" aka "css modules".

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35023434/11613622) has an example of using local stylesheet for each component. Also, there are various libraries, as mentioned in this [post](https://medium.com/@dmitrynozhenko/9-ways-to-implement-css-in-react-js-ccea4d543aa3), which can come handy for you.

Go through this [article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-ways-to-style-react-components-in-2019-30f1ccc2b5b), and pay attention at method 4 there. CSS modules is one of the best solutions in case you are experiencing CSS overlapping.

PS: react-native and react-js are two different tags!

You can understand react routing [here](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91), if you have some doubt over it. (Mentioning this because of tag!)